# What is the Lutheran view of he atonement of Christ on the cross?

Tags: lutheranism, atonement, gospel

According to Lutheran teachings (Martin Luther, Lutheran confessions, any Lutheran Church, Lutheran theologians, etc.), why did Jesus Christ had to die on the cross, and what did this accomplished?

Comment: Like most Protestants, they probably teach all the major views on the atonement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why did Jesus Christ had to die on the cross

Because Adam sinned and damaged our relationship with God. Something needed to be done to restore that relationship, and nothing we humans could do would suffice.

> what did this accomplished?

Salvation. Through Christ, we are reconciled to God and receive eternal Life through belief in Him. "I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me." (John 14:6) Christ is the *propitiation* (atonement) for our sins (1 John 2:2).

Some articles for further reading:

- [What we believe about Christ and redemption](https://wels.net/about-wels/what-we-believe/this-we-believe/christ-and-redemption/)
- [Why did Jesus die?](https://www.livinglutheran.org/2017/04/why-did-jesus-die/)